# Map network drive by IP (3rd octet)

Tags: hard-drive, ip, dhcp, network-drive

I would like to map the correct network drive (from several ones) to a computer using the IP assigned by DHCP through a batch script.

So when the computer connects and i.e. gets allocated the IP 192.168.**1**.10 via DHCP, he should map the network drive to 192.168.**1**.11.

If the computer gets the IP 192.168.**2**.10 via DHCP, he should map the network drive to 192.168.**2**.11. And so on and so on.

So I would like to allocate the right network device IP using the third octet of the computer's IP. The netword drive IP's are static. Only the computer's IP is random (DHCP) in the network.

The script schould look something like this I guess:

1. check IP --> ipconfig | findstr IPv4 (or network interface ""Ethernet"?)
2. split IP to 4 octets (or tokens?)
3. map to specific network drive (from a list?) through 3rd octet --> net use z: \PATH-NETWORK-SHARE\FOLDER-NAME

I hope you can help me here out!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that (assuming each host has only one IP address) :

```
@echo off
set address_begining=192.168
set host_octet=11
set ip_address_string="IPv4 Address"
REM Get IP Address
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:%ip_address_string%`) do set ip_addr=%%f
REM Get 3rd octet
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in ('echo %ip_addr%') do set third_octet=%%c
net use z: \\%address_begining%.%third_octet%.%host_octet%
```

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using PowerShell, since it comes with Windows anyway, and the steps are quite straightforward (as they would be in any sensible programming language):

> check IP --> ipconfig | findstr IPv4 (or network interface ""Ethernet"?)

```
$result = (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -AddressFamily IPv4)

$client_addr = $result[0].IPAddress
```

> split IP to 4 octets (or tokens?)

```
$octets = $client_addr.Split(".")
```

> map to specific network drive (from a list?) through 3rd octet

For example, if the server is always 192.168.x.11:

```
# array elements are numbered 0..3
$octets[3] = 11

$server_addr = $octets -join "."
```

> net use z: \PATH-NETWORK-SHARE\FOLDER-NAME

```
net use Z: "\\$server_addr\The_folder"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that works! One more question regarding a splitted subnet (into /25 with 126 available hosts). Does following if/elseif rule makes sense for you?



`$result = (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -AddressFamily IPv4)
$client_addr = $result[0].IPAddress
$octets = $client_addr.Split(".")
if ($octets[2] -eq '1' -And $octets[3] -In 2..125) {net use Q: "\\192.168.1.64\FileShare"}
elseif ($octets[2] -eq '1' -And $octets[3] -In 129..253) {net use Q: "\\192.168.1.193\FileShare"} `

Sorry for the format...

Comment: Yeah, from the scripting side, that seems like it should work fine. (I do kind of question the entire idea of this thread, however. It seems like something much better done via either DNS or Active Directory OU-based Group Policy than this kind of IP-based assignment...)

Comment: Also since you're dealing with IP network ranges, it might make much more logical sense to ask "is this address in 192.168.1.0/25?" instead of manual octet comparison. [Here's a PowerShell function I wrote for CIDR matching.](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/lib/cidr.ps1)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for the help! I will take a look at the function! Makes definitely more sense.